# how do I fix whitespace in my SED causing issues

Tags: sed

I'm having trouble with SED

what I want to replace:

```
image: thing:1.2.3
```

what I want it to be:

```
image: myrepo/folder1/folder2/opensource/thing/thing:1.2.3
```

what I am getting:

```
image: myrepo/folder1/folder2/opensource/thing/ thing:1.2.3
```

what I am running:

```
sed -e 's/image:\s/image:\ myrepo\/folder1\/folder2\/opensource\/thing\//' thing-deployment.yaml > thing-deployment.yaml.UPDATED
```

I think I'm close, but I'm mising something. What is it please?

Comment: `awk '$2 = "myrepo/folder1/folder2/opensource/thing/" $2'`

Answer (score 0):

You could change your delimiter to avoid so much back slashes in your code.

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's|th.*|myrepo/folder1/folder2/opensource/thing/&|' input_file
image: myrepo/folder1/folder2/opensource/thing/thing:1.2.3
```